# How to read excel file in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I have tried to read excel file to follow the following tutorial.
http://code.psjinx.com/xlsx.js/
But I have failed to read excel file for undefine situation in the following highlighted line.... I have tried it in  IE11.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                    type: 'binary'
                });

                obj.sheets = XLSXReader.utils.parseWorkbook(workbook, readCells, toJSON);
                handler(obj);
            }

            **reader.readAsBinaryString(file)**;
```

Comment: Could you specify: are you going to upload your Excel file from desktop or load from server?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer describe, if you are going to load xlsx file from server. For uploading there is another code.

**OPTION 1:** This is a procedure, which works in [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library:

See files: [15utility.js](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/version-0.0.35/src/15utility.js) and [84from.js](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/version-0.0.35/src/84from.js) for example

```
readBinaryFile(filename,true,function(a){
    var workbook = X.read(data,{type:'binary'});
    // do what you need with parsed xlsx
});

// Read Binary reading procedure
// path - path to the file
// asy - true - async / false - sync

var readBinaryFile = utils.loadBinaryFile = function(path, asy, success, error) {
    if(typeof exports == 'object') {
        // For Node.js
        var fs = require('fs');
        var data = fs.readFileSync(path);
        var arr = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        success(arr.join(""));
    } else {
        // For browser
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", path, asy); // Async
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var data = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
            var arr = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            success(arr.join(""));
        };
        xhr.send();
    };
};
```

**OPTION 2:** you can use Alasql library itself, which, probably, can be easier option.

```
alasql('SELECT * FROM XLSX("myfile.xlsx",{headers:true,sheetid:"Sheet2",range:"A1:D100"})',
     [],function(data) {
     console.log(res);
});
```

See the example here ([simple Excel reading demo](http://alasql.org/demo/003xlsx)) or here ([d3.js demo from Excel](http://alasql.org/demo/005d3)).